# Is there a way to return a dataframe from Python to R ?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, return

I'm using the system() function to trigger a Python script from R,
The python script writes a data frame into a .csv file which then needs to be imported to R. I was wondering if I could directly return the data frame from Python to R.

**R**

```
command = "python"
path2script='"/Desktop/testing_connection.py"'
allArgs = path2script
output = system2(command, args = allArgs, stdout=TRUE)
```

**Python**

```
df_temp = pd.read_csv('/Desktop/items.csv')
print(df)
```

I want to return a dataframe from Python to R
Currently 'output' is being created as a character vector.

Comment: So, you would like to convert a `pandas` dataframe to it's equivalent `R` object using `pandas`?

Comment: I don't know about conversion, I just want to do some data manipulation on it using R, presently I'm writing the data frame to a .csv from python and then importing that .csv file into R

Comment: You can use feather for this. Available in both python and r and saves the hassle of figuring out what the structure of the csv file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Feather](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/) format may accelerate your code.

I am not aware of a way to have one dataframe in r that you can access in python. The reason I doubt it is possible is that it is two different software, so the interoperability of data is really difficult to implement(if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Install [rpy](http://rpy2.bitbucket.org/). `rpy` is a simple, easy-to-use interface to R from Python. It enables one to enjoy the elegance of Python programming while having access to the rich graphical and statistical capabilities of R.
The `feather` format as suggested by a commentator may also  be of help if file I/O is mostly what you want it for.